# ASP NET Dataset Column name format

Tags: asp.net-core, uppercase, snakecasing

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 project which serves APIs.

Some of my apis interact with an Oracle DB, to get some dataset

Here is a short example of what one of my api does:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/GetMySpecificData")]
    public IActionResult getData()
    {
        ...
        var ds = new DataSet();
        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(query, connection);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        return Ok(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
```

In my Oracle DB, column names are UPPER_SNAKE_CASED and I expect my Api to return the Dataset with  the same format for the property names. (Example : USER_ID). Instead my client receives a different format for column names : useR_ID.

I don't know at all how to fix this, but what I want is to receive property names with the same format that it is set in the DB Column Name

I use this piece of code in my startup.cs ConfigureServices function :

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()
```

Maybe I have to add some options to specify this behaviour but I have no idea.

Comment: FYI OracleDataAdapter has been deprecated. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260
Source:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what I need is maybe to make Newtonsoft.Json case sensitive.

What I ended up to do is the following :

```
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson( options =>
        {
            options.UseMemberCasing();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

**Starup.cs**

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
{
    jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
})
```

In Asp.net Core 3 by default PropertyNamingPolicy is camelCase and set it to null will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried this already, and there are no changes when I use this.
I tried to put it after / before the AddNewtonsoftJson() line.
If I remove the AddNewtonsoftJson() Line I get an error "Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported and should be avoided" after request my api